# Magento: How to use getNameInLayout() from layer/filter/price.php

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to modify a Magento extension and distinguish from which column in the layout the price filter (Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Price) is called. The idea is that the price filter should look and behave a bit different in the left navigation bar compared to the price filter above the content.

I was trying to use $this->getNameInLayout() in the price.php (which worked fine in other Blocks, e.g. Catalog_Block_Layer_View) but won't do so in this one. Any ideas or suggestions on how to get the information on which column called the price filter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know which model is being used on a particular controller and the corresponding layout files; use this extension:

### http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/easy-template-path-hints.html

[image]

http://www.magepsycho.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/f/r/frontend-template-path-hints.png (bigger screenshot)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The issue is less which model and file is being used. My issue is that $this->getNameInLayout() is not returning the information on the column that called the filter. It works within Catalog_Block_Layer_View (returning e.g. "catalog.leftnav"), but not within Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Price.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_View block is defined in layout and named as 'catalog.leftnav'

```
 <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
```

Sure, you can use $this->getNameInLayout() to get it name. But look deeper in _prepareLayout() method of that class. It dynamically creates layer filter blocks (including the Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Price). All of them doesn't defined in layout, therefore haven't names.